# why i am getting "no data found" error in oracle live even if i have the data that satisfying my conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1001,'BOOK','PINK',1500);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1002,'TABLE','BLUE',3500);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1003,'COVER','BLACK',1800);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1004,'PANT','WHITE',2500);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1005,'RIBBON','RED',1500);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1006,'RING','BLUE',3000);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1007,'CUP','RED',2500);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES(1008,'SHIRT','PINK',3000);

//query
SELECT PNO, PNAME
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE (COLOR = 'PINK') AND (COLOR = 'RED')
AND  SALE_PRICE < 2000;
```

Comment: Please add the creat table for PRODUCTS

Comment: There is no single row that satiisfies both conditions color='pink' and color='red'. The conditions in the WHERE clause are evaluated for *each* row. We know that if color='pink' evaluates to TRUE, then color='red' will evaluate to FALSE, and we know "true AND false" evaluates to "false". That's why no rows are being returned. (When converting the AND to OR, we need to be aware that AND has a higher order of precedence than OR, which means we are going to need to add some parens, or repeat the condition on sale_price.)

Comment: i wanted both true and also their sale price should less than 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have COLOR = 'PINK' and COLOR = 'RED', use OR instead

`SELECT PNO, PNAME FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ((COLOR = 'PINK') OR (COLOR = 'RED')) AND SALE_PRICE < 2000;`

You can also use IN clause also like this

`SELECT PNO, PNAME FROM PRODUCTS WHERE COLOR IN ('PINK', 'RED') AND SALE_PRICE < 2000;`

Comment: It's working thanks for the help this will solve another problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you don't have any entries with `PINK` *AND* `RED`. Use `OR` instead.

```
//query
SELECT PNO, PNAME
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE (COLOR = 'PINK') OR (COLOR = 'RED')
AND  SALE_PRICE < 2000;
```

This next part is just to quickly show you that you have an option when adding multiple inserts:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS(PNO,PNAME,COLOR,SALE_PRICE) 
VALUES
(1001,'BOOK','PINK',1500),
(1002,'TABLE','BLUE',3500),
(1003,'COVER','BLACK',1800),
(1004,'PANT','WHITE',2500),
(1005,'RIBBON','RED',1500),
(1006,'RING','BLUE',3000),
(1007,'CUP','RED',2500),
(1008,'SHIRT','PINK',3000);
```

Comment: Your insert query is wrong there must be only one values

Comment: oh. i see what you meant, VALUES(), not values. fixing/thanks

Comment: beware the order of precedence of `AND` and `OR`. The syntax shown in this answer has the potential to return rows with `color='pink'` with any value of `sale_price`. We can use parens to override the order of precedence, or repeat the condition on `sale_price`, or we can use IN ('pink','red'),

Comment: it's working but because of OR condition I am getting extra detail which for a SHIRT which is not satisfying my condition.

Comment: You have a pink shirt in your data though. Did you just need to add another filter in your WHERE?

Comment: @Mech: the syntax in this answer is *not* checking sale_price when color is pink, i.e. its equivalent to `color='pink' OR ( color='red' AND sale_price<2000 )`